# select parent of a tag with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xmi

I want to select the parent of an XMI tag in a for-each loop. 
Here's my input :

```
<XMI xmi.version='1.2' xmlns:UML="org.omg.xmi.namespace.UML">
    <XMI.content>
        <UML:Model xmi.id='eee_1045467100313_135436_1' name='Data'>
            <UML:Namespace.ownedElement>
                <UML:Package xmi.id='_9_0_bc102e5_1427365805826_580042_23'
                    name='migration2'>

                <UML:Package xmi.id='_9_0_bc102e5_1427365805826_580042_22'
                    name='migration'>
                    <UML:Class xmi.id='_9_0_bc102e5_1427367042666_255023_151'
                        name='Employee'>
                        <UML:Classifier.feature>
                            <UML:Attribute xmi.id='_9_0_bc102e5_1427367052819_893122_168'
                                name='cin'>
                            </UML:Attribute>
                        </UML:Classifier.feature>
                    </UML:Class>
                    <UML:Class xmi.id='_9_0_bc102e5_1427367042666_255023_152'
                        name='Employee2'>
                        <UML:Classifier.feature>
                            <UML:Attribute xmi.id='_9_0_bc102e5_1427367052819_893122_169'
                                name='cin2'>
                            </UML:Attribute>
                        </UML:Classifier.feature>
                    </UML:Class>
                    <UML:Class xmi.id='_9_0_bc102e5_1427367042666_255023_153'
                        name='Employee3'>
                        <UML:Classifier.feature>
                            <UML:Attribute xmi.id='_9_0_bc102e5_1427367052819_893122_170'
                                name='cin3'>
                            </UML:Attribute>
                        </UML:Classifier.feature>
                    </UML:Class>

                </UML:Package>
              </UML:Package>
            </UML:Namespace.ownedElement>
        </UML:Model>
    </XMI.content>
</XMI>
```

so to select  the UML:Package with XSLT I use the select option of the for-each loop :

```
<xsl:for-each
                    select="XMI/XMI.content/UML:Model/UML:Namespace.ownedElement/UML:Package">
                    <packagedElement>
                        <xsl:attribute name="xmi:type">uml:package</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="xmi.id">
                        <xsl:value-of select='@xmi.id' />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select='@name' />
                    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Is there any possibility to replace the

> `select="XMI/XMI.content/UML:Model/UML:Namespace.ownedElement/UML:Package"`

PS : I've tried */UML:Package and ../UML:Package but it didn't work out .
any help ?

Comment: Which `UML:Package`do you want to select? There are two of them, and you should probably select them by name. Btw, it's annoying that the code reaches out of the window due to your tabs.

Comment: I want to select every UML:Package in my input inorder to do my changes on it and keep the same hierarchy of the input file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For selecting all `UML:Package` elements, you can simply write

```
select="//UML:Package"
```

Comment: @Iheb I am glad you found the answer, but this does not "*select the parent of an XMI tag in a for-each loop.*".

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear.

> I want to select the parent of an XMI tag in a for-each loop.

This part is easy: just use `parent::*` or shortly `../*`.  But that would work only when you already are in the context of some node that has a parent. So your question:

> Is there any possibility to replace the
>
> ```
> select="XMI/XMI.content/UML:Model/UML:Namespace.ownedElement/UML:Package"
> ```

makes no sense in this scenario.

Comment: how can I use `parent::*` in the for-each loop ?

Comment: Use it for what? Please expand your question and explain what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok,
Use the parent::* in for-each loop in order to selecr the parent node

Comment: @Iheb I don't have time for this game. Selecting a node is not a goal of itself; presumably you are trying to select it in order to **do** something with it. Please go back and edit your question so that it includes the expected result. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve